# How can for i in ${VAR} ever work in bash, instead of for i in "${VAR[@]}"?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, syntax

If I try on my machine (with bash 3,4 and 5) the following command:

```
bash-5.0$ VAR=(1 2 3)
bash-5.0$ for i in ${VAR}; do echo $i; done
```

I get only one line with the `1`.

If I do the same on ZSH for example, it nicely writes the three lines with progressive numbers.

However in one of our production servers I found this:

```
bash -c "for i in ${MY_VAR}; do stuff with $i; done"
```

And by checking the logs it seems that it is actually iterating correctly!

How is this possible? Is it a particular version of bash I’m not aware of? Or some flag I should set? Or maybe the array was populated in a particular way?

Comment: To expand an array you need: `for i in "${var[@]}"; do ...` (with the `[@]`). (and don't use uppercase variable names).

Comment: My guess is that `MY_VAR` is a plain variable with spaces between "values", not an array at all. Not the best way to do this sort of thing, but it'll work as long as none of the values contain spaces or wildcards. And as long as you don't change `IFS`.

Comment: Exactly that. The code in question isn't using arrays at all, but is depending on word-splitting to divide a non-array string into tokens -- an error-prone practice (responsible for more [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) entries than any other) which should never be used in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "works" because the code isn't actually using an array at all.

```
export MY_VAR='1 2 3'
bash -c 'for i in ${MY_VAR}; do echo "Doing stuff with $i"; done'
```

...involves no arrays whatsoever; `MY_VAR` is a string being word-split and then glob-expanded.

Don't do that, *ever*, even if you really do need to iterate over items from a delimiter-separated string. The reliable alternative is to use `read -r -a my_array <<<"$MY_VAR"` to read your string into an array, and then `for i in "${my_array[@]}"; do echo "Doing stuff with $i"; done` to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
var=(1 2 3)
for i in "${var[@]}"; do
    do stuff with "$i"
done
```

You need `[@]` as shown. And don't use uppercase variable names. Now as to why it works on your production server: possibly because `MY_VAR` is defined as `MY_VAR="1 2 3"` (or something analogous), i.e., `MY_VAR` isn't an array (which is bad).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Bash evaluates `$arr` to `${arr[0]}`:

```
arr=(1 2 3)
echo $arr      # yields 1

arr[0]=999
echo $arr      # yields 999
```

With associative arrays:

```
declare -A h
h=([one]=1 [two]=2)
echo $h            # yields nothing

h=([0]=1 [two]=2)
echo $h            # yields 1
```

As others have pointed out, the right way to loop through an array is:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do ...
```